# UIApplicationShortcutItem in didFinishLaunching

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

According to Apple documentation :

> *It’s your responsibility to ensure the system calls this method conditionally, depending on whether or not one of your app launch
>   methods (application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: or
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) has already handled a
>   quick action invocation. The system calls a launch method (before
>   calling this method) when a user selects a quick action for your app
>   and your app launches instead of activating. The requested quick
>   action might employ code paths different than those used otherwise
>   when your app launches. For example, say your app normally launches to
>   display view A, but your app was launched in response to a quick
>   action that needs view B. To handle such cases, check, on launch,
>   whether your app is being launched via a quick action. Perform this
>   check in your application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: or
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method by checking for the
>   UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey launch option key. The
>   UIApplicationShortcutItem object is available as the value of the
>   launch option key.*

But why there is a need to handle this in didfinishlauncing/willfinishLauncing methods. If the app is in killed state, eventually it will call the performActionForShortcutItem method, so why there is a need to check in didfinish method?

Sample code:

```
//code




    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        var launchedFromShortCut = false
        //Check for ShortCutItem
        if let shortcutItem = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey] as? UIApplicationShortcutItem {
            launchedFromShortCut = true
            handleShortCutItem(shortcutItem)
        }

        //Return false incase application was lanched from shorcut to prevent
        //application(_:performActionForShortcutItem:completionHandler:) from being called
        return !launchedFromShortCut
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: Bool -> Void) {
        let handledShortCutItem = handleShortCutItem(shortcutItem)
        completionHandler(handledShortCutItem)
    }

    func handleShortCutItem(shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) -> Bool {
        var handled = false
        //Get type string from shortcutItem
        if let shortcutType = ShortcutType.init(rawValue: shortcutItem.type) {
            //Get root navigation viewcontroller and its first controller
            let rootNavigationViewController = window!.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
            let rootViewController = rootNavigationViewController?.viewControllers.first as UIViewController?
            //Pop to root view controller so that approperiete segue can be performed
            rootNavigationViewController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)

            switch shortcutType {
            case .Torquiose:
                rootViewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier(toTurquoiseSeque, sender: nil)
                handled = true
            case.Red:
                rootViewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier(toRedSeque, sender: nil)
                handled = true
            }
        }
        return handled
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It gives you the flexibility to decide - you can handle it "early" in didFinishLaunching - returning FALSE will inhibit performActionForShortcutItem from getting called later. Or you can return TRUE in didFinishLaunching, and performActionForShortcutItem will still get called.